# Web UI for openzipkin run from Docker image shows config.json error

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to get an openzipkin server running in a k8s cluster, starting with testing in a minikube. I'm beginner with k8s config, but here's what I've done so far:

```
$ minikube start
$ eval $(minikube docker-env)
$ kubectl run zipkin --image=openzipkin/zipkin --port=9411
$ kubectl expose deployment zipkin --port=9411 --type="NodePort" --name=zipkin-http
```

What I think I'm doing is starting a new pod and deploying the zipkin image, then exposing the Web UI at port 9411 via zipkin-http. After doing this:

```
$ kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox -- sh
$ nslookup zipkin-http
Server:    10.0.0.10
Address 1: 10.0.0.10

Name:      zipkin-http
Address 1: 10.0.0.101
$ wget -qO- zipkin-http:9411
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
$ wget -qO- zipkin-http:9411/config.json
{"environment":"","queryLimit":10,"defaultLookback":3600000,"instrumented":".*"}
```

Then I run the kubectl proxy so I can access the Web UI from my browser:

```
$ kubectl proxy --accept-hosts=".*"
```

Now if I browse to http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/zipkin-http/config.json I get the config file contents:

```
{"environment":"","queryLimit":10,"defaultLookback":3600000,"instrumented":".*"}
```

But if I browse to the root at http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/zipkin-http/ I receive an error:

```
Error loading config.json: undefined
```

The config.json it's attempting to load is the one at :9411/config.json. The request to load /config.json comes from a JS file that was loaded by the html in the root page.

Since it looks like I can get to the json file directly from both inside and outside the cluster, I'm confused as to why the JS file isn't able to load it. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web app is trying to access `config.json` at root (accessing as `/config.json` vs just `config.json` ) - that is http://localhost:8001/config.json . This would obviously be wrong as it should be http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/zipkin-http/config.json

There is a very simple solution for this - just run:

```
kubectl port-forward <name of the pod> 9411
```

Now just go to http://localhost:9411 and the UI should be up (tried and verified.)

You can get the name of the pod by doing `kubectl get pods`

PS: `kubectl proxy` is generally meant to access the Kubernetes API, and `kube port-forward` is the right tool in this case.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing something like this so I didn't have to know the pod name in advance (though there might be a better way to accomplish this): kubectl port-forward $(kubectl get pods -l "run=zipkin" -o 'jsonpath={.items[*].metadata.name}') 9411